# Spring Boot application with 2 databases simultaneously?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is there a way to run Spring Boot application with 2 databases in the same time using `@Profile`?

For example, for exercise purposes, I have 2 beans that are bind to 2 tables in MySQL database run in local, and I want to have another bean to do CRUD functionalities with table in H2 database. Is it possible to do that using the `@Profile` annotation on service layer in a way that I precisely say what properties file should that service use?

Comment: why would you need anything like that? you can easily have multiple datasources without having some additional config done

Comment: Yes, you can do this, and no, `@Profile` isn't the feature to use.

Comment: I was just asking myself if it is possible. So you think it is better to use 2 datasources ?